# Converting integral equation to its primary initial value problem

Tags: initial-value-problems, integral-equations

I converted below initial value problem to Volterra equation of second kind
$$
y'(x)-2xy(x)=e^{x^2}, \hspace{3mm} y(0)=1
$$
Supposing $u(x)=y'(x)$ and integrating both sides from $0$ to $x$ yields the Volterra equation corresponding to the above differential equation
$$
u(x)=2x+e^{x^2}+2x\int_{0}^{x}u(t)\,dt
$$
Now I tried to check whether my answer is right. I differentiated both sides with respect to $x$ I got
$$
u'(x)=2+2x\,e^{x^2}+2\int_{0}^{x}u(t)\,dt+2x\,u(x)
$$
Rewriting this in form of differential equation above we have
$$
u'(x)-2xu(x)=2+2x\,e^{x^2}+2\int_{0}^{x}u(t)\,dt \,,\hspace{3mm} u(0)=1
$$
But now the above differential equation I have gotten is not equal to the primary initial value problem. What's exactly wrong?

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti But should not the integral part in last equation be somehow eliminated so it becomes a proper differential equation like the primary initial value problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did nothing wrong. It is not expected to obtain the same equation since you are expressing the result using another function. The equation you obtained is the derivative of the original equation.

Comment: But should not the integral part in last equation be somehow eliminated so it becomes a proper differential equation like the primary initial value problem?

Comment: No, a first order differential equation in $y$ is a second order differential equation in $u$, so the integral remains if you insist in working with a first order equation

Comment: So it is not possible to get the primary initial value form? Then how am I supposed to know whether my answer is correct or not?

Comment: use that $u=y'$ and $\int u=y(x)-y(0)$